# Batching large amounts of data in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm configuring my consumer with the following

Pretty much pulled straight from Confluent docs. My concern is, I pass in number of bytes (500mb) and the length exceeds size of an integer. Probably a dumb question, but can I configure the consumer properties to accept a long or something? Getting an error since value is too large.

Docs look unbounded, but the type is `int` so not sure how that's possible:

```
max.partition.fetch.bytes: The maximum amount of data per-partition the server will return. Records are fetched in batches by the consumer. If the first record batch in the first non-empty partition of the fetch is larger than this limit, the batch will still be returned to ensure that the consumer can make progress. The maximum record batch size accepted by the broker is defined via message.max.bytes (broker config) or max.message.bytes (topic config). See fetch.max.bytes for limiting the consumer request size.

    Type: int
    Default: 1048576
    Valid Values: [0,...]
    Importance: high
```

Comment: The max size of a message is 1mb default...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all to make it clear: max int value in java is 2147483647.

2147483647 bytes ≈ 2.15 gb

Secondly, when you check source code of KafkaConsumer API, you will see that MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG parameter is being cast to Integer. So it is not possible to set it a value larger than the upper bound of Integer. It's kind of a design decision and cannot be changed.

Links to source code:

[link-1](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.java#L792)

[link-2](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/config/AbstractConfig.java#L173)